# Why does create-react-app create the App.js file as a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to learn React and I noticed that when I used `npx create-react-app my-project`, it created the `App.js` file as a functional component, as opposed to a class component, as it did in past versions. I found [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/6451) commit on create-react-app's repo where they changed it.

What I'm trying to figure out, is why they did this? I read [this](https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108) article on class components vs. functional components and as far as I understand it, functional components are stateless. I must be misunderstanding, or maybe just do not have the full knowledge in this area yet, as I cannot understand why we would **want** the main component for the entire app to be stateless?

P.S. I understand that the `App.js` file can be easily changed *back* to a class component, but I'm trying to understand why they would change it to default to a functional component.

Comment: I think: maybe its for new comers, to start using the latest functionality "hooks" early on. Thus changing App.js as functional component makes sense

Comment: Class-based components can be stateless too. FB pushes functional component and state hooks because in their opinion (which I agree with) it leads to cleaner and less buggy code. (Though the react hooks and dependencies introduced a whole new set of confusion to novice developers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React recommends using functional components and hooks [when possible](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), because class-based components can result in a few unnecessary difficulties:

> **Classes confuse both people and machines**

> In addition to **making code reuse and code organization more difficult**, we’ve found that classes can be a large barrier to learning React. You **have to understand how `this` works** in JavaScript, which is very different from how it works in most languages. You have to **remember to bind the event handlers.** Without unstable syntax proposals, **the code is very verbose.** People can understand props, state, and top-down data flow perfectly well but still struggle with classes. The distinction between function and class components in React and when to use each one leads to disagreements even between experienced React developers.

> Additionally, React has been out for about five years, and we want to make sure it stays relevant in the next five years. As Svelte, Angular, Glimmer, and others show, ahead-of-time compilation of components has a lot of future potential. Especially if it’s not limited to templates. Recently, we’ve been experimenting with component folding using Prepack, and we’ve seen promising early results. However, we found that **class components can encourage unintentional patterns that make these optimizations fall back to a slower path.** Classes present issues for today’s tools, too. For example, classes don’t minify very well, and they make hot reloading flaky and unreliable. We want to present an API that makes it more likely for code to stay on the optimizable path.

> To solve these problems, Hooks let you use more of React’s features without classes. Conceptually, React components have always been closer to functions. Hooks embrace functions, but without sacrificing the practical spirit of React. Hooks provide access to imperative escape hatches and don’t require you to learn complex functional or reactive programming techniques.

Using a functional component by default can make things easier for those learning React (and for those who already know React but prefer using functional components, which many do).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did also want to add one thing for any other newcomers that didn't realize that function components aren't really "stateless" per this doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html